# how to load a class in admin.py based on user permissions

Tags: python, django

I have been developing an application for `song link submission` in `django`, and I would like to make some field non-editable for the staff users in the admin area but the superusers can edit it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Register your models here.
from .models import SongLinks


class SongLinksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        readonly_fields=('ip','dedicated_to','dedicated_message')
        list_display = ('song_link','dedicated_to','dedicated_message','ip')
    else: 
        list_display = ('song_link','dedicated_to','dedicated_message','ip')
admin.site.register(SongLinks, SongLinksAdmin)
```

this gives me an error:

> ```
> if request.user.is_staff:
> ```
>
> NameError: name 'request' is not defined

**What is wrong with this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@admin.register(SongLinks)
class SongLinksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('song_link', 'dedicated_to', 'dedicated_message', 'ip')

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return ('ip', 'dedicated_to', 'dedicated_message')
        return ()
```

Comment: Maybe also check that the user is not super user as well in the same if clause?

Comment: For future usage ModelAdmin have [a lot of helpful methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods).

Comment: it throws a type error for the super user but works for staff

Comment: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Updated with missing return value and added the superuser check. My guess would be that all your admin users already are staff and really the only check that is required is to check if they are not superusers.

Comment: thanks a lot dude solved in the end just add else and return id to override it

Comment: Great. I've added the register decorator as an alterantive way of admin registration.